# Maximum transmission range with SimpleObstacleShadowing in Veins

Tags: veins

I would like to understand which is the maximum transmission range (maximum distance beetween two vehicles exchanging messages) having set the SimpleObstacleShadowing analogue model.

So I read this [article](http://www.ccs-labs.org/bib/sommer2011computationally/sommer2011computationally.pdf) and I would like to exploit formula (6) to reach my purpose. Unlikely I didn't understand if the attenuation got by obstacles (Lobs[dB]) is given in Veins or through which parameters I can actually compute it.

I also read this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/w487s3eT8VMhttp://) but I think those formulas do not hold for this model.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum distance between two nodes in the network is calculated by the *SimplePathLoss* model. It calculates the distance according to the used transmission frequency and MCS.

The *SimpleObstacleShadowing* additionally adds attenuation if the transmitted message hits an obstacle.

Both are analogue models and can be configured via the config.xml which is read by the *Decider* module of the physical layer.

***Update:***
Also there is the *maxInterfDist* parameter which determines the distance an ideal communication can have at most.

Comment: If I got it, it's that distance factor, isn't it?

Comment: Can `maxInterfDist` be set only globally or also per entity?